# Create nodes programatically from third-party api using batch processing in drupal

Tags: php, json, cron, drupal-7, batch-processing

I m trying to make web application in Drupal where I'm fetching **millions of records** using **themoviedb API.**
I want to store all the API data in a different content types using entity reference. 
the first question, will it be possible to fetch data from API and use a batch process to store the data in Drupal cms?

the second question, will that affect the performance of the website and how to perform this operation to avoid any issues?

also, can we do it using Drupal cron?

if you have any better alternative to the above, please guide me.

Comment: Do you have a node type already defined when fetching from the API ??

Comment: Yes, I'm going to create custom **content types** based on API response values.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to make insertions of millions of records, I suggest you to use transactions https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/transactions, which speeds up insertions considerably.

If you use cron for this, I recommend you to check Elysia Cron https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron

I will affect performance, of course, but I can't tell you how much. You can do this process in hours where your site is not busy. ElysiaCron is very handy for this kind of problems.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, Beto. I will check the solutions provided by you.